# How to compile System.Console in C#

Tags: c#, .net

So I was taking a look at the source code for System.Console [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,d9447a1cf3bff2b0).

I thought it would be interesting to see how it is implemented and possibly make some changes myself.

So I copied the source code directly from Microsoft's example and pasted it in Visual Studio.

It does not compile.

```
Win32Native.Beep(frequency, duration);
```

There are several lines like this one. All of them with the same error message.

```
Error   32  The type or namespace name 'Win32Native' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

There are about a hundred error messages, but only 4 unique-ish ones. Including the main one above.

```
Error   85  The name '__Error' does not exist in the current context    

Error   89  Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Win32Native.CHAR_INFO')

Error   18  The property or indexer 'System.Console.InternalSyncObject' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor
```

I strongly suspect I am lacking some assembly references. If you know what they are let me know, so that I can compile this.

Comment: It may be difficult to get that source to compile if you are selectively copying files. The specific issue you mention is related to missing Win32Native.cs: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs

Comment: You just forgot to copy a whole bunch of extra code.  Located elsewhere, like the pinvoke declarations in Win32Native.  Just use referencesource.microsoft.com and click on the identifier to find the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't you know that Microsoft publishes compilable source code at GitHub?

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Console/src

To compile it, follow [this guide](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/wiki/Developer-Guide).

The rational behind is like this,

- The Reference Sources are already available before under a non-OSI compliant license. Due to missing files, you cannot compile them. Now Microsoft puts them under an OSI compliant license.
- Microsoft is publishing reference sources plus some other private source files together to form the new open source .NET Core stack at GitHub.

You can now find https://github.com/dotnet/corefx and https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr . More things are coming, so you can keep an eye on http://dotnet.github.io/

Comment: I had heard only that Microsoft was open sourcing their stack. I thought what I found was indeed that. But it is not. It appears what you have a link to is the real thing.  That being said, you should edit your answer to note that the source code they published there is incomplete, meaning not everything has been made available yet.

Comment: Also, whoever gave you the minus 1 likely inferred a derogatory tone in your answer. You may consider rephrasing it, before others do the same.

Comment: No, this can't be correct.  OpenStandardInput() has a completely different definition in the link you sent me.

Comment: OK. Let me expand the answer to include more about Microsoft's open source strategy.